# Structure of a large library with typescript

Tags: typescript, package

I am developing a library for engineering calculations which is becoming quite complex in structure. Currently I use UMD to allow me to add or extend modules and have recently become interested in converting this over to typescript.

Say the library is called englib it might have several modules like the following

- englib.thermo.pengrobinson
- englib.thermo.srk
- englib.convert
- englib.maths

Ideally each of these modules would be a separate npm module or bower package so functionality can be cherrypicked.

Additionally englib.thermo would be its own module that provides base data and classes for englib.thermo.pengrobinson and englib.thermo.srk.

What is the best way to structure this using namespaces and modules in typescript so I can maintain the organisational hierarchy while also allowing module consumption to be cherry picked?

Comment: I'd say this is a complex problem that needs to be approached from multiple perspectives, and cannot be answered in one concise post. Either way, you might want to extensively utilize reexporting to organize your modules the best you can.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, however unsure whether I should have an englib namespace everything sits in and how that even works across multiple packages.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally each of these modules would be a separate npm module

This is the way to go. Note that TypeScript understands `node_modules` out of the box : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

> or bower package

Also bower is dead : https://twitter.com/basarat/status/671930970690347009